# Expected non-nullable lint warning for LiveData in Android Studio 2020.3.1 P2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lint

Here's the code in question:

```
private val _cropRequiredLiveData = SingleLiveEvent<MediaContent>()
fun crop(): LiveData<MediaContent> = _cropRequiredLiveData

private fun onDownloadComplete(content: MediaContent?) {

    if (request.isCropEnabled
        && content != null
    ) {
        _cropRequiredLiveData.value = content
        return
    }

    // ...
}
```

`content` variable in following line shows me a lint warning:

```
_cropRequiredLiveData.value = content
```

The warning is:

> Expected non-nullable value

If I replace `content` with a `content!!` or `requireNotNull(content)`, I get another lint warning saying:

> Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!) on a non-null receiver of type MediaContent

> Redundant 'requireNotNull' call

Is there something I can do to make the lint happy?

Here's the `MediaContent` file:

```
@Parcelize
class MediaContent(
    val metadata: MediaMetadata,
    val source: MediaSource,
    val path: String
) : Parcelable

fun MediaContent.toFile() = File(path)
```

Comment: Also, this lint warning is with me from a few weeks.

Comment: Still experiencing this on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `this._cropRequiredLiveData.value = content`. Not sure why but it works for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me back when you answered, but today, out of nowhere, when I tried this, it started working for the time. I think this might be due to me using -ktx versions of lifecycle and arch dependencies in the newer projects. Thank you.