# How to set my "java-library" library as a kotlin library in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have added a new module to my project from *File > New > New Module > Java or Kotlin Library*. I set language as Kotlin and DSL as Kotlin DSL. However, my `build.gradle` lists project as `java-library` in `plugins`. Here's my build.gradle:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    // kotlin("jvm") // this is something I wanted to try
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
}
```

How should I go about making it a Kotlin library?

---

Some context: I didn't really need to make this change. But, recently, I have started seeing `enum` warnings in my exhaustive `when` statements stating following:

> Enum argument can be null in Java, but exhaustive when contains no null branch

Since this enum is declared in new module (in a kotlin file using kotlin syntax), I think my current project is assuming that this module is a java-project and hence, the warning.

---

An answer, to this question, might also help me solve the issue with my LiveData treating variables from another module as null even after checking for nullability.

```kotlin
val result = response.data // CallResult is a class in another module
if (result == null) {
    errors.emit(generalErrorOf(response.message))
    return@launch
}

_someLiveData.value = result!!
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491459)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your `build.gradle` file to properly configure your module as a Kotlin library, by replacing [`id("java-library")` with `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "<kotlin_version>"`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm), and including Kotlin standard library and any other Kotlin-specific dependencies:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "<kotlin_version>"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
}

kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            kotlin.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
        }
        test {
            kotlin.srcDirs("src/test/kotlin")
        }
    }
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

There is an optional `kotlin` block to [set source directories](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/gradle-domain-specific-language-sourceset). The `java` block is for compatibility settings.
Sync your Gradle files after making these changes.

---

Regarding the LiveData lint warning, try and Modify your `ViewModel` to handle nullable `MediaContent`:

```kotlin
private val _cropRequiredLiveData = SingleLiveEvent<MediaContent?>()

fun crop(): LiveData<MediaContent?> = _cropRequiredLiveData

private fun onDownloadComplete(content: MediaContent?) {
    if (request.isCropEnabled && content != null) {
        _cropRequiredLiveData.value = content
    }
    // 
}
```

`_cropRequiredLiveData` is declared as `SingleLiveEvent<MediaContent?>` to accept nullable values. That change requires handling nullability in parts of your code where `_cropRequiredLiveData` is observed.

Or: if you are confident that `content` is non-null when assigning it to `_cropRequiredLiveData`, you can [use `!!`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34342413/6309) after checking `content != null` in the `if` condition:

```kotlin
private fun onDownloadComplete(content: MediaContent?) {
    if (request.isCropEnabled && content != null) {
        _cropRequiredLiveData.value = content!!
    }
    // 
}
```

---

> Although, I updated the projects as you said, it didn't help me resolve both the issues.
> But, to be fair, I found out that "`Java Enum Nullability`" issue only happens when I observe any `enum` using `LiveData` (which is a java class), and not because the `enum` class was declared in another module.

So the "Java Enum Nullability" issue surfaces when observing enums through `LiveData`, which is indeed a Java class. That could be because of the way Kotlin and Java handle nullability differently, and how Kotlin interacts with Java code.

In Java, all non-primitive types can be null, including enums. When Kotlin interacts with Java types, [it often treats them as nullable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) to maintain Java's nullability contract. That is likely why you are seeing warnings related to enum nullability when using `LiveData` with enums.

To address this, when observing enums through `LiveData`, explicitly check for null values even if it seems unnecessary in Kotlin. That approach ensures safety when dealing with potential nulls from Java classes.

```kotlin
myEnumLiveData.observe(this, Observer { enumValue ->
    if (enumValue != null) {
        // Handle non-null enum case
    } else {
        // Handle null case, even if it is unexpected in Kotlin
    }
})
```

Another possible approach: create a custom wrapper for `LiveData` that enforces non-null values. That can help bridge the gap between Kotlin's non-null types and LiveData's Java-based nullability.

```kotlin
class NonNullLiveData<T : Any>(private val liveData: LiveData<T?>) : LiveData<T>() {
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        liveData.observe(owner, Observer { it?.let(observer::onChanged) })
    }
}
```

Use this wrapper to observe your enums, filtering out null values implicitly.

Or, you can also use Kotlin's [safe calls (`?.`)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls) and the [Elvis operator (`?:`)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) when dealing with potentially nullable LiveData values.

```kotlin
myEnumLiveData.observe(this, Observer { enumValue ->
    val safeEnumValue = enumValue ?: return@Observer // Handle or return on null
    // Use safeEnumValue which is guaranteed non-null here
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although, I updated the projects as you said, it didn't help me resolve both the issues. But, to be fair, I found out that "Java Enum Nullability" issue only happens when I observe any enum using `LiveData` (which is a java class), and not because the enum class was declared in another module.

Comment: About the `LiveData` lint issue, I have tried `!!` as I mentioned in the linked question at the bottom of this question. It starts showing "Unnecessary null-assertion" in this case. When I do a file refactor/reorganise-code/commit action, it removes `!!` and marks it as an error again. :') Same with `requireNotNull(..)`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Since, I already check for nullability in the ViewModel, I will go ahead with safe-call option for now. About the second LiveData lint warning, using `this@ViewModelName.liveData` when setting value has indeed started removing the lint warnings for me. So, I will just start using that for the time. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @rupinderjeet Good call. If using a qualified `this` (like `this@ViewModelName.liveData`) resolves the lint warnings and works well in your context, then using `this@ViewModelName.liveData` for `LiveData` is a good solution. It can help clarify the scope and context, especially in nested lambdas or inner classes, which might be why it is addressing the lint issues.